# Eclipse won't start on raspberry pi 4 - "An error has occurred. See the log file"

Tags: debian, java, raspberry-pi, eclipse, raspbian

I've just bought my first raspberry pi and installed Eclipse using the `sudo apt-get install eclipse` command however when trying to run it I get the following error:

> An error has occurred.  See the log file
>   /home/pi/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1572457927583.log

The log file says the following:

> !SESSION Wed Oct 30 17:38:46 GMT 2019 ------------------------------------------
>   !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-10-30 17:38:46.634
>   !MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
>   !STACK
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
>       at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

The version of Java I am running is openjdk 11.0.3 on Raspbian

Comment: Your Eclipse is very old and won't run with Java 11. Either use an older Java or a newer Eclipse (2019-09 is the current version).

Comment: @greg-449 Unfortunately that's not possible--eclipse.org does not build for ARM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the packaged version try downgrading openjdk to openjdk-8.

[This bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=891956) has more information on the issue. The problem you are having is one of many that kept eclipse out of the last Debian version.

Another alternative is to download it from [upstream](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: The Eclipse 3.8.1 version in Debian/Raspbian is 7 years old.